# How to split strings in columns, into rows (on two rows, that match position) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

Ok, here we go. My first ever post and question.

I'm using SQL server 2019. I have a table, im interested in two columns from this table.

Both columns contain array-like data (they are both a set of strings, comma delimited. I want to take each substring from the columns and show them alone in their own 'cell' and instead have many rows.

Now, I can get it to work with one of the columns using STRING_SPLIT. However, when I use string split on both columns, I dont get the order I need. i.e for example see below

```
column1: 'my_fav_drink','my_fav_colour','my_fav_avenger'

column2: 'coffee','blue','dr_strange'
```

The position of the strings will always match, so the 3rd entry in column 1 will always relate to the 3rd entry in column 2.

But when I run the string split, **the orders get messed up**

I have tried self joins, sub selects and messed around with order by's but I just can't seem to get it working in order.

I have searched online for while, so Im not just coming to the community without first trying, and I will appreciate any help or guidance, and I looked here for the answer of course but I have not had any luck.

Update: Please consider the following:

1. This was not built by me, I'm diving into this without a tech specification having to go through the DB, i'm sure some of you will know my pain. If I get approval, I will re-design this but I can't for now (I could make another table though). The data comes in automatically from a machine like this as a list of strings
2. There are about 50 values in each column

Desired output is:

[image: desired_output_table]

The whole point of this is so that I can do analysis in another software (again, was a request) but the array can't be sorted out in the software.

Thanks guys,

Much appreciated

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: *DON'T* store such values in databases in the first place. That's a critical bug, breaking the most fundamental design rule. There's no implied order in SQL (the language) either, unless it's specified by an `ORDER BY` clause. SQL Server has no arrays, and you can't just emulate them with strings

Comment: Given the contents of those values, you should be using a table with columns named `my_fav_drink`, my_fav_colour`, `my_fav_avenger`. The columns could be in the main table (eg user) or a related table (eg preferences). If the fields are highly variable and *not* used for filtering, you could consider storing those values in an XML or JSON field instead.

Comment: I get the whole dont store them this way in the first place, maybe I can have some influence, but its not my database and the values come in automatically from a machine like this. The guy who made it left one day after I joined so Im trying to work my way through what hes done. If I can redo the whole thing from entry, I will, but this is just to do some analysis for now

Comment: I should also mention, theres about 50 values in each, does that change the genral concensus on making them all columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best solution is to change the design, but if you need to parse the input data, you  may a try a JSON-based approach. The idea is to transform the values from `column1` and `column2` columns into valid JSON arrays (`my_fav_drink, my_fav_colour, my_fav_avenger` into `["my_fav_drink", "my_fav_colour", "my_fav_avenger"]`) and parse the arrays using `OPENJSON()` and default schema. The result from the `OPENJSON()` execution is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and the values in the `key` column are the indexes of the elements in the input array.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   column1 varchar(100),
   column2 varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO Data (column1, column2)
VALUES ('my_fav_drink,my_fav_colour,my_fav_avenger', 'coffee,blue,dr_strange')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, j1.[key]) + 1 AS [Number], j1.[value] AS [Label], j2.[value] AS [Value]
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(d.column1, 'json'), ',', '","'), '"]')) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(d.column2, 'json'), ',', '","'), '"]')) j2
WHERE j1.[key] = j2.[key]
```

Result:

```
Number  Label           Value
1       my_fav_drink    coffee
2       my_fav_colour   blue
3       my_fav_avenger  dr_strange
```

Comment: Thank you! I needed a solution quickly and you have provided it. It's working great, I can now analyse the data no problems and I have added a task in the backlog to redesign the table as a permanent solution. I really appreciate the help

Comment: update: Your solution helped me to get what i needed. I have since gained approval and redesigned all these tables :) whoohoo

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.column1,b.value as Label
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY string_split(cast(d.column1 as varchar(max)),',')b

SELECT d.column2,c.value as Value
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY string_split(cast(d.column2 as varchar(max)),',')c
```

Try this approach

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Your method of storing values is really, really bad.  For instance, guaranteeing that the two columns have the same number of values is troublesome.  And then imagine what happens if one of the values could have a comma!

There are basically four alternatives.

1. If you know what the columns are, store them!  If doesn't matter if some rows have `NULL` values.  That's fine.  If you want to get fancy, you might have different sets of columns stored in different tables.
2. A variation on (1) is to use [sparse columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-ver15).  This allows more columns than would normally be allowed on the row -- assuming most of the values are `NULL`.
3. A key-value store.  That is, you would have another table with multiple rows per "entity" and one row per key/value pair.  Such an EAV data model (entity-attribute-value) can be quite powerful, but it generally assumes that all values are the same type and precludes the definition of foreign key relationships.
4. Use XML or JSON to encode the values.  In conjunction with putting used fields in column, this provides extensibility and often reasonable performance.

Note that your method of storing multiple values in a string with headers in another string is not on this list.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I think option 3 might make sense here. Please note this is not my method, Im coming into this new and taking over from a guy who left a day after I joined. Theres a lot of questionable stuff in this db

Comment: I wanted to say thanks again, I think a redesign of whats been done is the least painful thing to do. I just need to look into the data coming in and how this is happening.